# GNU linker script - split code in two memory regions

Tags: linker, split, gnu, ld, scatter

I am trying to create a liker script that splits the code into two memory regions for the code and a separate for the BSS.

The two code sections are to linked together but to be loaded separatly
What ever I try, the code always mixeup. I tried different versions, alignments sections with no success.

Here is a description of what I want:

**Flash:**

```
------------ 0x0
| CODE 1   |
|          |
------------
| fill to  |
|alignment |
|          |
------------ 0x200000
| CODE 2   |
|          |
------------
```

**loaded to Memory:**

```
------------ 0x5c010000
| CODE 1   |
|          |
------------
.          .
.          .
------------ 0x81500000
| CODE 2   |
|          |
------------
```

I saw the linker manual " Input Section Example" but it doesn't work for me.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Filename:      startup.lds
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-arm", "elf32-arm", "elf32-arm")*/

OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)

ENTRY(__main)


SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x5c006000;
    __bss_start = .;
    .bss : {    *(EXCLUDE_FILE (../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdownload.o
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdriver.o
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/xllp_udc.o)
        .bss) }
    .bss2 : {
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdownload.o (.bss)
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdriver.o (.bss)
     }

    . = ALIGN(4);

    . = 0x5c010000;

    .__main = .;

    . = ALIGN(4);

    .text : {
        *(EXCLUDE_FILE (../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdownload.o
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdriver.o
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/xllp_udc.o)
        .text)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    }

    .rodata : { *(EXCLUDE_FILE (../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdownload.o
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdriver.o
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/xllp_udc.o)
        .rodata) }

    . = ALIGN(4);

    .got : { *(EXCLUDE_FILE (../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdownload.o
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdriver.o
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/xllp_udc.o)
        .got) }


    . = ALIGN(4);

    __egot = .;




    . = ALIGN(4);

    __data_start = .;
    .data : AT (__egot) {*(.data) } =0xFFFFFFFF
    __data_end = .;

    . = ALIGN(16);
    _seg_CODE_end_ = .;

/*  ASSERT((_seg_CODE_end_ <= 0x5c020000), "Error: Code size to big")*/


    . = ALIGN(0x20000);
    __topofcode__ = .;

    . = 0x81500000;
    .__usb_code_start = .;
    .usb_code 0x81500000 : 
    AT(__topofcode__) 
    ALIGN(0x20000)
    SUBALIGN(0x20000)
    {
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdownload.o (.text)
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdriver.o (.text)

        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdownload.o (.rodata)
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdriver.o (.rodata)

        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdownload.o (.data)
        ../../release/eshel_lte_evb3/usbdriver.o (.data)
    }

    __bss_end = .;

}
```

Comment: Is `__bss_end` really placed correctly?